# Windows phone 8.1 - watching a remote file

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

My question might sound a bit generic, but I was hoping to find a solution anyway. What is the best way to keep "watching" for a remote file change in WP 8.1's api?

The current context: I am using a web service to retrieved all orders of a shopping cart software. Currently fetching it (xml) using the httpClient class, reading the stream and converting to an object. 
Is there a way to keep checking after X seconds, so that I can raise  a new toast notification once a new order is placed? 
What would the best approach be?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over the web service, then the best solution is to integrate push notification inside the server's logic. Otherwise, you can spawn a background thread that polls for the file each X seconds and check for changes, but that would not be as good as a push notification.

Comment: You mean something like this? http://www.windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone/notifications/how-to-send-and-receive-push-notifications-for-windows-phone-8/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WinRT equivalent of a file watcher to raise an event when the XML file changes. See a tutorial here:

http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2012/10/03/filesystem-change-notifications/

Comment: Uhm, but that uses the local folder, is it possible with remote files?

Comment: Sorry I didn't pick up on exactly what was happening. If you own the web service, then you can use a standard file change notification and use that to send a notification to your app... Assuming you're using windows to host the web service.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve by using the Windows Push Notification Service in the end: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202940(v=vs.105).aspx